# How can I update my SQL table in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I created a program that requires a database and I am using Visual Studio and SQL Server to do it.

My problem is that I cannot update my table. I found the solution [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

My code is below:

```
this.customersTableAdapter.Update(this.northwindDataSet.Customers);
tabelAdapter.Update(ABCDatabaseDataSet**.Barber)**;
```

But it gives me an error that the `ABCDatabaseDataSet` does not have `Barber`. There is just `BarberDataTable` or `BarberRow` there is not a `Barber` table.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probably best off doing this with ADO or better LINQ.  Heres an ADO example:

```
    var thisConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=ServerIP/Name;Data Source=Database;Initial Catalog=Database;User ID=User;Password=Pass;Trusted_Connection=False");
    thisConnection.Open();

    var updateSql1 = "UPDATE dbo.Customer " +
                     "SET barber = 'I Barber People !' " +
                     "WHERE customerID = 5";

    var UpdateCmd1 = new SqlCommand(updateSql1, thisConnection);
    UpdateCmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    thisConnection.Close();
```

Too much to place here but here is a good Linq (database) tutorial [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246861/LINQ-to-Entities-Basic-Concepts-and-Features)